# Arithmetic expression parse

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to parse an arithmetic expression into a binary tree represented as (list left right value). This is my code:

```
(define (parse exp)  
(let loop ([e exp])
  (cond
   ((and (list? e) (or (not (null? (car e))) (not (null? (caddr e)))))
        (list (loop (car e)) (loop (caddr e)) (cadr e))))))

(parse '(1 + (2 * 3)))
```

The result is this and I don't know where from the void appears.

```
'(#<void> (#<void> #<void> *) +)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the base case of the recusion (here it's the `else` in `cond` form):

```
(define (parse exp)  
  (let loop ([e exp])
    (cond
      ((and (list? e) (or (not (null? (car e))) (not (null? (caddr e)))))
       (list (loop (car e)) (loop (caddr e)) (cadr e)))
      (else e))))
```

Testing:

```
> (parse '(1 + (2 * 3)))
'(1 (2 3 *) +)
```

`#<void>` is the result of "falling through" the `cond` form (i.e. no condition matched, and there's no `else`):

```
> (void? (cond))
#t
```